# ManytoMany relations in Laravel, retrieve data from related tables and display in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have two tables related by many to many relation in Laravel Framework. I can display data from each table separately, but not through relation by taking one record from the 1st table and checking related records in the 2nd table. In tinker it accesses data fine.

Relations:

```
public function underperformances() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Underperformance::Class);
    }
...
  public function procedures() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Procedure::class);
    }
```

My resource controller part:

```
...
use App\Underperformance;
use App\Procedure;
...

public function index()
  {
       $books = Underperformance::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(9);
       $procedures = Procedure::all();
       return view('underpcon.underps', compact('books', 'procedures'));
   }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/underps', 'UnderpsController@index');
```

If I try to display data like this:

```
@foreach($procedures as $procedure) 
  <li>{{$procedure->underperformances}}</li>
 @endforeach
```

I get such format to the browser:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Spare part not taken before service","description":"tekstas","level":"1","costs":600 ...
```

This is correct data from related table, but I cannot select further the specific column from that table. For example this does not work:

```
@foreach($procedures as $procedure) 
  <li>{{$procedure->underperformances->id}}</li>
 @endforeach
```

Nor this one:

```
 @foreach ($procedures->underperformances as $underperformance) 
 <li>{{$underperformance->id}}</li>
@endforeach
```

1. How do I select records of the related table and display specific data from that table?
2. What would be a conventional way to do this?

Comment: Please, be so kind and give me clarification when downvoting so I can make improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach($procedures as $procedure) 
  <li>{{$procedure->underperformances->id}}</li>
 @endforeach
```

^ This right there `$procedure->underperformances` will return a **collection**, not a single item, so you need to treat it as array, you will not be able to access the `id` directly, you can either `@foreach` that, or use the `pluck` method in [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck).

Comment: There are two models, **Underperformance** and **Procedure**. Tables **underperformances** and **procedures**. Pivot table contains **underperformance_id** and **procedure_id**. So it may be the issue. I will try this fix.

Comment: you need to check the results of that `$procedure->underperformances`, try `dd($procedure->underperformances);`, i assume it's null.

Comment: After dump it returns the two related records. But the problem is how do I select specific collumns from those two related records. Renaming did not work and laravel documentation provides a sample where _id in table is singular and relation methods are plural, so the issue should be not the naming?

Comment: what do you mean two related records?

Comment: ah , i see what i missed there, `$procedure->underperformances` doesnt' return a single item, it's returns a collection, you need to `@foreach` that as well

Comment: `@foreach($procedure->underperformances as $_underperformance)...`..

Comment: or you can play around with `collection` methods, like `$procedure->underperformances->pluck('id')->implode(',');` this will extract the id from them, and use `implode`... just a scenario you can use in case you don't wanna use foreach and prefer to have a simple output in a single line

Comment: then it makes sence that I need double `@foreach`. Meanwhile the second sollution would be `collection` methods. I will use this reference. That answers my questions.

Comment: yes, except the part about singula/plural is incorrect/confusing according to laravel documentation